# Are the graphs of f(|x|) and f(|−x|) same or not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

Graph of $f(x)$ :

[image]

Original question says that the graph of $f(x)$ is given above. According to this , which of the following functions have continuous graphs in real numbers?

I-) $|f(x)|$

II-) $|-f(x)|$

III-) $f(|x|)$

IV-) $f(|-x|)$

**Answer:** I,II,IV

What I know :

- $|x|=|-x|$
- $f(|x|)$ reflects the graph to the right of the y-axis in the y-axis. Ignore the left hand side part of the graph

**What am I asking ? :** Because of $|x|=|-x|$ , i thought that the graph of $f(|x|)$ and $f(|-x|)$ must be same ,and because of the fact that " $f(|x|)$ reflects the graph to the right of the y-axis in the y-axis. Ignore the left hand side part of the graph " , i thought that both $f(|x|)$ and $f(|-x|)$ have discontinuous graphs.

However , the given answer is $I,II,IV$.According to this answer , the graph of $f(|x|)$ and $f(|-x|)$ are different , but i do not think so. (I agree with I and II but not IV)

Can you explain me why the graph  of $f(|x|)$ and $f(|-x|)$ are different ?

**NOTE:** When i asked it to my teacher , he said that $f(|-x|)$ reflects the graph to the LEFT of the y-axis in the y-axis ,so IV is continuous but it does not make sense to me . What do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(|x|)$ and $f(|-x|)$ have the same graphs because they're the same function. The answer key is wrong; $f(|x|)$ is not continuous (particularly there's a discontinuity at $2$). Perhaps they have a typo and intended option IV to be $f(-|x|)$; in this case it is continuous and would be a valid choice.

Comment: when i ask my teacher , he said that $f(|-x|)$ means reflects the graph to the LEFT of the y-axis in the y-axis, so it is continuous

Comment: what do you think about his answer ?

Comment: @sipaşşş I think he's confused. If anything he's probably thinking of $f(-|x|)$.

Comment: By the way , can we also say that the graph of $|f(x)|$ and the graph of $|-f(x)|$ are the same by the same reason ?

Comment: @sipaşşş yes exactly. Minus signs inside absolute values make no difference

Comment: To make sure , lastly , the graph of $|y|=f(x)$ and $|-y|=f(x)$ are the same ,right ?

Comment: @sipaşşş it doesn't make sense to speak of the graph of $|y|=f(x)$. Strictly speaking, you should only speak of "the graph of the function $f$". So, you're not using the right terminology.

Comment: why does not make sense ? we draw it graphs such that reflect $y \geq 0$ to x -axes

Comment: @sipaşşş it doesn't make sense, because that's not how we use the terminology. The term **graph** is reserved for functions. $f$ is a function, so it makes sense to speak of its graph. And I didn't want to be super formal earlier, but to be proper, I should have said something like "the function $f_1:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $f_1(x)=f(|x|)$" or  "the function $f_2:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $f_2(x)=f(-|x|)$" or something like that. What you're writing is an equation $|y|=f(x)$. An equation is not the same thing as a function.

Comment: It's kind of like asking why the moon is not a planet like the Earth... after all, they're both round and orbit around the sun. The answer is, it's just not the right terminology.